# How use eclipse debug hadoop wordcount?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, hadoop

I want to use eclipse debug the wordcount, because I want to see the job how to run in the JobTracker. But hadoop use Proxy, I don't know the concrete process that job how to run in the JobTracker. How should I debug?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off debugging "locally" against a single-node cluster (e.g. one of the sandboxes supplied by Cloudera or Hortonworks): that way you can truly step through the code as there is only one mapper/reducer in play. That's been my approach at least: usually the problems I had to debug were to do  with the contents of specific files; I just copied over the relevant file to my test system and debugged there.

Comment: thank you. But I want to debug job in the JobTracker not in LocalJobRunner. How shou I do?

Comment: that's my point: how are you going to be able to do that? there's no way of knowing which map task is going to process which split and having a break point hit by X parallel processes will cause a headache or two !

Comment: I use pseudo-distributed model，can I do it？

Comment: @gwgyk: I would try it in standalone mode.

Comment: in standalone mode，it will use LocalJobRunner class, not JobTracker class， right？ Is there a big difference between them？

Comment: not that I've noticed: it's a different entry point, but you still have access to the hadoop internals for debugging purposes (mapper, reducer, combiner classes etc.)